# Compile java class

Tags: java, jacorb

I m trying to compile this java class _MyServerStub.java but I get this error

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt) 
                                                          ^
stock/_MyServerStub.java:83: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).normalCompletion();
                                            ^
stock/_MyServerStub.java:88: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt) 
                                                          ^
stock/_MyServerStub.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).exceptionalCompletion(re);
                                            ^
stock/_MyServerStub.java:94: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt) 
                                                          ^
stock/_MyServerStub.java:95: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServantObjectExt
location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).exceptionalCompletion(err);
                                            ^
6 errors
```

_MyServerStub.java is a generated stub from jacORB so the code is not wrong.

Comment: I am using Jacorb with java if that's the question

Comment: Add the JacORB jars to your claspath

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you can include following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-corba_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```